# Out of nowhere, ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote hot me too

Tags: ssh, connection

See similar:
[Out of nowhere, ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host](https://serverfault.com/questions/326088/out-of-nowhere-ssh-exchange-identification-connection-closed-by-remote-host)

Today, 6/19/12 attempting to ssh to the same host as usual 
ssh replied

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

two additional attempts failed

```
ssh -v $RWS
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to Real-World-Systems.com [174.127.119.33] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/dgerman/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/dgerman/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dgerman/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dgerman/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

ping host was successful,

ftp host was successful,

ssh now successful,

```
ssh -v $RWS
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to Real-World-Systems.com [174.127.119.33] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/dgerman/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/dgerman/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dgerman/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/dgerman/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_4.3 pat OpenSSH_4*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'real-world-systems.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/dgerman/.ssh/known_hosts:5
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/dgerman/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/dgerman/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

**++++ What gives?? +++++++++++**

Mac OS X 10.4.7 , 
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011,

```
/Users/dgerman/.ssh > ls -la
total 24
drwx------    7 dgerman  staff    238 Jun 19 15:46 .
drwxr-xr-x  389 dgerman  staff  13226 Jun 19 15:46 ..
-rw-------    1 dgerman  staff   1766 Feb 26 18:25 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--    1 dgerman  staff    400 Feb 26 18:25 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--    1 dgerman  staff     67 Feb 26 18:27 keyfingerprint
-rw-r--r--    1 dgerman  staff   6215 May  1 08:11 known_hosts
-rw-r--r--    1 dgerman  staff    220 Feb 26 18:26 randomart
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the post you linked to. Most likely you were temporarily unable to resolve. But you can now ssh again so this problem magically solved itself. In my experience many of these oddball ssh issues relate to a resolving issue of one sort or another.

Comment: By "temporarily unable to resolve" do you mean DNS?

Comment: Yes I mean DNS, the remote server wasn't able to resolve your IP. Almost always a nameserver (or multiple) as configured in your DNS settings is used to resolve IP addresses.

Comment: Thanks, although I find this rather odd, especially since dig reports ;; SERVER: 192.168.1.1#53 i.e. my router is currently resolving the address.

Comment: Yes it is a bit odd, however what you reported in the comment above is consistent with your question. There you reported it started working again. Hence I would expect your server to resolve fine now, but it may not have been temporarily at the time the ssh session failed.

Comment: Thanks again, If it reoccurs I'll look to DNS before "try this, try tat until it works"